# Keeping AJAX Requests Serial in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I have some code that I [recently moved to FastCGI for a backend](https://serverfault.com/questions/1060978/change-default-number-of-processes-with-fastcgi-on-apache) to fulfill AJAX requests from a jQuery based front end. The problem is that while FastCGI largely accelerates it, I actually get a negative performance issue from two jQuery AJAX requests hitting it in too quick of succession. What I'd like to do is "lock" AJAX so that the requests happen in serial rather than parallel -- each request only takes around 180ms to perform, but if the second request goes in before the first one has completed, the second request ends up taking about a second and a half instead.

I suppose the obvious way that I could make it serial is to put an `$.ajax` request inside the `.done` portion of the previous request, but the requests are in to different functions and need to stay that way since they don't always need to be fired together -- just frequently so. Imagine this:

```
function loadCategories () {
   // Do some organizing stuff, set url, etc.
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: parameters,
        type: "GET",
        dataType : "json",
    })
      .done(function( json ) {
         //process sidebar category data.
      });
}

function loadArticles () {
   // Do some organizing stuff, set url, etc.
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: parameters,
        type: "GET",
        dataType : "json",
    })
      .done(function( json ) {
         //process article data.
      });

}
```

Both of these functions are called in a third function:

```
function loadPage (parameters) {
    loadCategories(parameters);
    loadArticles(parameters);
}
```

What I'd like to do is keep the `.done` and `.always` logic within those two functions, *but also* return a promise from these functions so that I could then use `$.then` to keep `loadArticles` from firing until `loadCategories` has completed. I've tried to figure out the right way to do this, but haven't succeeded in the right way to do this yet.

Comment: Something seriously wrong if your HTTP server can't handle simultaneous requests. What happens if you get more than one client accessing your site at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the functions return the `Deferred` object that `$.ajax()` returns, and then you can wait for this in the calling function.

```js
function loadCategories() {
  // Do some organizing stuff, set url, etc.
  return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: parameters,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
    })
    .done(function(json) {
      //process sidebar category data.
    });
}

function loadArticles() {
  // Do some organizing stuff, set url, etc.
  return $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: parameters,
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
    })
    .done(function(json) {
      //process article data.
    });
}

function loadPage(parameters) {
  $.when(loadCategories(parameters)).then(
    function() {
      loadArticles(parameters)
    };
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you -- this did exactly what I need. I suspect there is a server issue I need to address, but for now, this has shaved a full second off of the load-time. Thank you so much!